# iPhone Safari CSS rotation bug

Tags: css, iphone, mobile-safari, screen-orientation

I have a small mobile phone app that is acting strangely on the iPhone/Mobile Safari. The page renders and works great when it's orientation is vertical. When I rotate the phone horizontally some, but not all elements on the page resize correctly. Some header elements will stay nearly their same size, maybe increasing by 10%, others will double in size.

Has anyone run into this? My first thought was that the css could have a mix of sizes based on ems and px's but finding every size element and converting them to em's didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because Mobile Safari on iPhone & iPod Touch does automatic font-size adjustment.

You can disable it with the following css rule,

`html {-webkit-text-size-adjust:none}`

More info from [Safari Reference Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006510-SW16)

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried including a viewport meta tag, such as this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Otherwise, you could try creating orientation-specific CSS stylesheets and swap them out w/ javascript when the orientation change event fires, but I prefer the meta tag method above.

Comment: I did have a viewport meta tag. This was a pretty strange bug and I never actually found a solution (It was part of an internship and I went and got job so I'm no longer on the project).

Comment: Wow just encountered the same problem. added the scale values to the meta tag fixed it on refresh. (Before I only had the user-scalable.)

Weird though.